# Deleting dependent records from a table/list

Tags: user-behavior, workflow

It would be great to have ideas around how to approach below scenario.

User wants to delete a Item "X" from a table A. But item "X" is being referenced by multiple items from Table B , Table C and Table D.

Whats the best flow to allow user to delete Item "X" ?

we cannot automatically delete referenced items from Table B , C and D. We should let the user make that choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Present a warning to the user about the consequences of deleting item X, i.e.,

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRMn9e.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The 'consequences' could be a cascading delete (as I've shown above), or dereferencing X from the various related items (i.e., "Item One will no longer know about X"), depending on your use case.

Comment: I think this would work when we just have one item from each table being deleted. When we have for example Item 1 , 2 , 3 from Table A and Item 1,2,3 from Table B , this might not work well.

Comment: May be something like "Table A  50items , Table B 30 Items , Table C 20items" in the box which currently shows "item One Item two Item three" .. Also what do you think about adding a "X" next to these table names which would enable users to click to delete all linked records from that table ?

Comment: That could work - although if you're going to get much more complicated that that, you may want a dedicated UI for this type of action.

Comment: Yea that's true. I should think of limiting user control or create a UI for complete control